# Compare two python lists and expand the shorter list to the length of the longer list

Tags: python, list

The question header I have is a little confusing and I just wasn't sure how too explain it well with just the header.

I have two lists.

```
list_1 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
list_2 = [10,40,70]
```

Expected output:

```
new_list = [10,0,0,40,0,0,70,0,0]
```

How should I do this? The following is what I have and I wasn't sure what was wrong:

```
def expand_list(complete_list, to_be_expand_list):
    expanded_list = []
    for i in complete_list:
        for j in to_be_expand_list:
            if i == j:
                expanded_list.append(j)
            else:
                if expanded_list[-1] != 0:
                    expanded_list.append(0)

    return expanded_list
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code. Does it error? If so where is the traceback? Does it execute, but not do what you expect?

Comment: If order doesn't matter: `[i[1] for i in list(itertools.zip_longest(list_1, list_2, fillvalue=0))]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def expand_list(full_list, short_list):
  return [x if x in short_list else 0 for x in full_list]
```

This uses a list comprehension to generate a list which is the length of the complete list, but contains only those elements which were in the short list, replacing all the rest with zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_1 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
list_2 = [10,40,70]

new_list = list_1[:]

for i, v in enumerate(list_1):
    if v not in list_2:
        new_list[i] = 0

print new_list
```

result:

```
[10, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0]
```

This checks the positions in list_1 which aren't in list_2, and sets them to 0

Answer (score 2):

You are going over all the `to_be_expand_list` for each item on the `complete_list` and in (almost) each iteration you append an item, so at the end you will have `len(list1)*len(list2)` items.

You should change it to:

```
def expand_list(complete_list, to_be_expand_list):
    expanded_list = []
    for i in complete_list:
        if i in be_expand_list:
            expanded_list.append(i)
        else:
            expanded_list.append(0)
    return expanded_list
```

If you look for simpler approach you can use [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
[x if x in list2 else 0 for x in list1]
```